# Find files in PhpStorm by exact names without having similar names being prioritized

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

When **searching a file** in PhpStorm, the IDE suggest me files with similar names even if there is a file with the exact same name I am searching (even with file ending).

[image]

This is probably based on how much I used a file in the recent history and that's great! I don't want to avoid this intelligent search behaviour.

Therefor I am wondering, if there is a key, or hotkey, or char I can type, to tell PhpStorm to not include anything wildcard here or give me the exact matching file **first**?

(Simply navigating down the list, does not look like a big deal here, but I cut the screenshot and there were over a dozen more files in between)

Comment: Sounds like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-315980